# How do you echo out radio input types?

Tags: php, html

I have an html form that echos back text and radio inputs. The form waits for all values to be filled before echoing them back out.

Here is an example of my text input:

```
<input type='text' name='occ3' size='20' value="<?php echo $occ3; ?>"/>
```

Here is my radio output:

```
<input type='radio' name='o2' value='yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' name='o2' value='no'>No
```

How do I output the selected radio after a user submits information? Please help

Comment: `echo $_GET["o2"];` (if the form is `GET` - otherwhise use `$_POST`)

Comment: Isnt there any submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the radio buttons to default to what was submitted, you can do:

```
$o2 = $_REQUEST['o2'];
?>
<input type='radio' name='o2' value='yes' <?php if($o2 == 'yes') echo 'checked' ?> >Yes
<input type='radio' name='o2' value='no' <?php if($o2 == 'no') echo 'checked' ?> >No
```

Answer (score 1):

php

```
  if (isset($_POST['radio'])) { // if options was checked
      echo $_POST['radio']; // echo the choice
    else
      echo "you nothing was selected.";
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='radio' name='o2' value='yes' <?php echo $o2 == 'yes' ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>Yes
<input type='radio' name='o2' value='no' <?php echo $o2 == 'no' ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>No
```

Comment: It would help to explicate a touch. Code-only answers tend to help the OP less than questions with some explanation of why the code produces the intended result.